# How to complete for loops inside of a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

Im trying to create a large object for Treant.js.  I input an Id and it queries my database and returns an array of people that were referred by that ID.  I then want to do the same with each returned person and their children so as to create a tree.  The problem I am running into is that my function only creates one 'branch'. When it gets to a dead end it doesn't finish the for loop one level up.  Any help would be appreciated.
[here is a visual representation of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se5e0.png)

```
                function getChildren (id) {
                    var url = "core/downline.php";
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function(result) {
                            array = JSON.parse(result);
                        }
                    });
                    return {
                        text: {
                            name: "insert name",
                            text: id,
                        },
                        children: array
                    };
                };

                function createStructure(id) {
                    var startingObj = getChildren(id);
                    function finishStructure(startingObj) {
                        for(i=0; i < startingObj.children.length; i++) {
                            startingObj.children[i] = getChildren(startingObj.children[i].id);
                            if(startingObj.children[i].children !== null) {
                                finishStructure(startingObj.children[i]);
                            }
                        };
                        return startingObj;

                    };
                    startingObj = finishStructure(startingObj)
                    return startingObj;
                };
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer I’ve been receiving the data just fine because of the “async: false”.  I just need help completing the tree

Comment: Your loop variable is a global variable as you have it written currently. This will cause major issues with recursion because every recursive call will be referencing the same `i` variable. Use `var` or preferably `let` and see if your issue persists

Comment: @mhodges THANK YOU! That was what was causing the issue.  I need to make a habit of declaring ‘i’ in my loops

Comment: @DalThePal sorry about that — didn't notice the `async:false`

Comment: @MarkMeyer no worries thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @DalThePal Glad that worked for you! As for Mark Meyer's comment, he is absolutely right that you will have issues with the asynchronous calls. I understand that currently you are using an `async: false`, however, less and less browsers are supporting synchronous XHRs, which makes that a less-than-optimal solution. You can fairly easily fix that issue with `Promise`s or `async/await`

Comment: @mhodges noted and will fix. thanks all

Comment: @DalThePal Great `=)` Please be sure to mark my answer as accepted if that is what resolved your issue. Thank you! Welcome to SO

Comment: The use of "use strict" and the use of a linter, such as `eshint` will do wonders at catching those kinds of bugs.

Comment: You should read how to use [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) more effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop variable is a global variable as you have it written currently. This will cause major issues with recursion because every recursive call will be referencing the same `i` variable. Use `var` or preferably `let` and see if your issue persists.

```
for (let i = 0; i < startingObj.children.length; i++) {
  ...
};
```